# How to reference resources to save in settings - Visual Basic 2008 .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, reference, settings, embedded-resource

I'm trying to save a setting that keeps what background image I'm currently using.

If it's an external file, there is no problem, i can just get the .location and set it in a String setting to store it.

But, if I want to store an image resource as a setting, how do i do it?

I know i can store rawdata, like bitmap information, but then i can't set that type of data to the my.background.

I don't know if the question should be: "how do i reference resources", but the my.resources.resource.methodsList doesnt contain anything that seems to be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("resource name")` to read a resource by string.  Here's some example code that shows you how to get a list of all the embedded images from the resources which includes both their string name and the image object itself:

```
Public Class EmbeddedImage
    Public Sub New(ByVal name As String, ByVal image As Image)
        _name = name
        _image = image
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _name As String

    Public ReadOnly Property Image() As Image
        Get
            Return _image
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _image As Image
End Class

Private Function getEmbeddedImages() As List(Of EmbeddedImage)
    Dim images As List(Of EmbeddedImage) = New List(Of EmbeddedImage)()
    Dim resources As ResourceSet = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, True, True)
    For Each resource As DictionaryEntry In resources
        If TypeOf resource.Value Is Image Then
            images.Add(New EmbeddedImage(resource.Key.ToString(), CType(resource.Value, Image)))
        End If
    Next
    Return images
End Function
```